# When is "Cochran–Mantel–Haenszel" like "McNemar's test"?

Tags: mcnemar-test, cochran-mantel-haenszel

In Wikipedia, the article on [Cochran–Mantel–Haenszel statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%E2%80%93Mantel%E2%80%93Haenszel_statistics) states that "The [McNemar test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test) can only handle pairs. The CMH test is a generalization of the McNemar test as their test statistics are identical when each stratum shows a pair."

Could someone please show when the two tests give the same results? i.e.: in what parameterization does the Cochran–Mantel–Haenszel test give the same results as The McNemar test?

Comment: Some of this Q&A https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/327520/why-does-sas-cochran-mantel-haenszel-seems-different-than-others?rq=1 may help to reveal more about the confusion about CMH.

Comment: Cochran's *Q* test is to McNemar's test as a repeated measures ANOVA is to a paired *t* test. Do not know about CHM, though, so gonna go read about that.