# Chi-square on a categorical variables (derived from continuous distribution)

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, chi-squared-test, continuous-data, frequency

We know that Chi-Square can be used with categorical data (such as Male/Female, Republican/Democrat, etc).  However, I convert my original `continuous` data to `categorical` variables and then use Chi-square analysis on it.  Is the approach correct?  It has been pointed out to me at [continuous vs categorical logistic regression for marks and admission](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95263/continuous-vs-categorical-logistic-regression-for-marks-and-admission/95277?noredirect=1#95277) that using such an approach with logistic regression may be flawed.  Not sure if Chi-square is also affected the same way.

The actual scenario is given below (can also be seen on the mentioned weblink) :

I have a list of marks scored by students in Science (X, between 0 to 100%) and whether they went to college to or not (Y).
High marks in science showed a higher concentration of college admits and low marks had the second best hit rate (students went for Arts degree, etc). Scores in the intermediate range had a lower hit rate. Most students have lower scores in Science.

I divided my sample into

5 bins: 0-10, 10-20, 20-80, 80-90, 90-100.  Found Chi-Sq to be significant.  My main question is - Is categorizing such marks into bins correct?

Comment: Because the $\chi^2$ distribution and associated tests shows up in so many different applications, please tell us *how* you plan to use it. It would also be helpful to know how you selected the cutoffs for binning your continuous variable, because that often affects the test.

Comment: It is rarely correct to convert continuous data to categorical data. It loses information.

Comment: @PeterFlom Conventionally speaking you are right.  But in my distribution, most of the universe is between say 0-5 but most of the events are between -5 to 0 bin.  Chi-Square helps me show that there is an association between these bins and events.  Again, I'm not sure if categorizing them was a good decision to begin with.  Should I simply drop the chi-square analysis?

Comment: Maybe quantile regression is something to look at in your case.

Comment: @Peter True, but there is a distinction between "correct" (the word used in the question) and "useful" (which is what I think is really being asked). When you use a less powerful procedure (*i.e.*, one that "loses information") and it still indicates a significant difference (as suggested, but not stated, in the question), then you have what you need to draw a conclusion. Perhaps of more import at that point is how one would measure the size of the effect: using irregularly spaced bins--especially ones adapted to the data, as here--can create a real challenge in that regard.

Comment: Is the dependent variable is dichotomous (wants to go college, doesn't want to) or ordinal or what?  You might want to look at splines, regardless.

Comment: @PeterFlom I have found some examples where continuous data was binned to create categorical data (http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/chigf.htm).  My point is I think Chi-Square is used to compare predicted vs observed distribution.  Continuous data can be binned to obtain predicted & observed values.

Comment: It certainly *can* be, but should it be?

Comment: @PeterFlom As long as `can be` approach is correct, I should be fine.  My final decision is not based on Chi-square analysis but instead on Logistic regression.  Chi-square is used just to begin the analysis by showing bin levels and events have some sort of relationship.  I'm aware that I can skip it totally and jump directly to LR, but I'd prefer to keep this approach. Thanks.